# Solution to T(n) = 2T(n/2) + log n

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, master-theorem

So my recursive equation is `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + log n`

I used the master theorem and I find that a = 2, b =2 and d = 1.

which is case 2. So the solution should be `O(n^1 log n)` which is O(n log n)

I looked online and some found it O(n). I'm confused

Can anyone tell me how it's not O(n log n) ?

Comment: Make me see the [tag:python] angle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should not be case 2, but case 1.

With `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + log n` the critical exponent of `c_crit = log_2(2) = 1` as you found, I think correctly. But certainly `log n` is `O(n^c)` for *some* `c < 1`, even for all `0 < c < 1`, so case 1 applies and the whole thing is `O(n^c_crit) = O(n^1) = O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `d` in the master theorem. The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)#Generic_form) on the Master Theorem states that you need to find `c = log_b a`, the critical exponent. Here the `c = 1`. Case 2 requires we have `f(n) = Theta(n log n)`, but in reality we have `f(n) = log n`. Instead, this problem falls into case 1 (see if you can figure out why!), which means `T(n) = Theta(n)`, as you found elsewhere.

Comment: i didnt understand how log n can be written as n^of something

Comment: Remember that a function being `O(n)` means that the function is bounded above by the a constant multiple of `n`. Is `log n` bounded above by a constant multiple of `n`? Try graphing them on http://desmos.com/calculator.